Flutter Getx GetmaterialApp.router with AutoRoute
So, i've been working on this company for about 4 month, they want to implement getx for navigating at their project, but they already using auto router, it could take so much time to rewrite everything from scracth, so is there a way to navigating using getx when we already using auto route?

i've already using GetmaterialApp.router but when i navigate using Get.to(PageName()), it show:
You are trying to use contextless navigation without
a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
If you are testing your app, you can use:
[Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
for a [GetMaterialApp].
